# sequelize-typescript cannot add model

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have the following model `Person.ts`:

```
type PersonAttributes = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

type PersonCreationAttributes = Optional<PersonAttributes, 'id'>;

@Table({ tableName: 'alarms' })
class Person extends Model<PersonAttributes, PersonCreationAttributes> {
  @PrimaryKey
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Index
  @Column
  id: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  name: string;
}

export default Person;
```

And then in sequelize:

```
const DBInstance = new Sequelize(config.db.database, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
  host: config.db.host,
  dialect: config.db.dialect as Dialect,
  repositoryMode: true,
  logging: config.db.debug,
});

DBInstance.addModels([Person]);

Person.build({
  id: "111",
  name: '111',
});

export default DBInstance;
```

The above code gives this error:

```
ModelNotInitializedError: Model not initialized: Member "build" cannot be called. "Person" needs to be added to a Sequelize instance.
```

Please advise.